# Excel VBA not able to trace all rows that was changed via copy & Paste

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am new to VBA, I have a requirement of tracing all modified rows in excel. The excel file is expected to have millions of records out of that only few columns or rows are expected to be modified by user. To save time I plan to update only the modified records back to sql rest delete it.  I managed to get the below code to do work as per the expectation but only if the user modifies manually. If the user copies and pastes multiple row only the first records is marked as modified rest is not.

My requirement to track anything that changes via manually or copy&paste in that workbook

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim cw As Long
    rw = [Sheet1!b8].CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    cw = [Sheet1!b8].CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
    lcw = ColumnLetter(cw)
    Dim xrng As Range   
    Set xrng = Range("c1:" &lcw & rw)
    If Not Application.Intersect(xrng, Range(Target.Address)) _
        is Nothing Then
           If Target.Row > 1 Then Cells(Target.Row, 1) = "M"
           End If
    End If  
        
End Sub

Public Function ColumnLetter(ColumnNumber As Long) As String
    ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, ColumnNumber).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Don't understand the exact logic of your code, but you will have to loop over all rows of `Target`

Comment: My requirement was to tag each and every populated row that is modified  with "M"  but the my code was not working on copy& paste.  Yes you have pointed it correctly I was not sure where should I place the Loop. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clean what you're gonna do with `Intersect` but here you are a snippet to mark all affected rows with an M in the 1st column:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
     Dim v

     Application.EnableEvents = False
     For Each v In Target
         if v.Row > 1 And v.Column > 1 Then Cells(v.Row, 1) = "M"
     Next
     Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Notes:

`For Each` loop manages multiple cells selection.

`Application.EnableEvents = False` is needed to prevent the sub from firing on changing `Cells(..., 1)`

This code is not perfect because it overwrites `Cells(..., 1)` as many times as many columns the affected range contains. But you can keep it this simple if it is not too slow. Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you very much this works perfectly for the requirement.  Additional Query  Is it possible to restrict to the number of rows and column populated in that excel and not all rows.

Comment: @Pravin `Target` contains only the selected cells. A single cell or the affected range. The user can delete or paste a block of data beyond the populated range and you need to do something with that, too. Without knowing enough about the business needs I'd suggest to tailor the ` If v.Row > 1 ...` row to limit further processing on rows with real data.